# ORM SQlite не работает

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

В основном потоке

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String mail = etEmail.getText().toString();


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnAdd:

            Contact contact = new Contact(mail, name);
            contact.save();

            break;

        case R.id.btnRead:

            List<Contact> allContacts = Contact.listAll(Contact.class);

            textView.setText(allContacts.toString());

            break;

        case R.id.btnClear:

            Contact.deleteAll(Contact.class);

            break;
    }
```

И отдельный класс

```
  import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Contact extends SugarRecord{

    String name;
    String mail;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String mail, String name) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", mail='" + mail + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

В AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"> <!--Используйте этот атрибут дословно-->

    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db"/>
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example.viktor.anabstract"/>
```

Запускаю приложение, ввожу данные, жму добавить и приложение вылетает

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.viktor.anabstract, PID: 12949
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: SugarContext has not been initialized properly. Call SugarContext.init(Context) in your Application.onCreate() method and SugarContext.terminate() in your Application.onTerminate() method.
                      at com.orm.SugarContext.getSugarContext(SugarContext.java:22)
                      at com.orm.SugarRecord.getSugarDataBase(SugarRecord.java:35)
                      at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:416)
                      at com.example.viktor.anabstract.TestActivity.onClick(TestActivity.java:79)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10620)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Лог вылета где?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.viktor.anabstract, PID: 12949
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: SugarContext has not been initialized properly. Call SugarContext.init(Context) in your Application.onCreate() method and SugarContext.terminate() in your Application.onTerminate() method.

Comment: добавил к вопросу

Comment: Автор, вы нам что-то не договариваете. NullPointerException возникает в случае когда в какую-то функцию вместо объекта передаётся null. Кроме того, мне очень не понятно, где у вас в коде контакта описан метод save

Comment: List<Contact> allContacts = Contact.listAll(Contact.class);
listAll(Contact.class) - это конечно статик метод? Иначе я его в оракл доках не нашёл.

Comment: C orm я впервые работаю, пример взял отсюда: http://www.fandroid.info/orm-dlya-uproshheniya-raboty-s-sqlite-v-android-na-primere-sugar-orm/. У него там все работало. На деле же да, на строчку List<Contact>... тоже ругается.

Comment: Мне всё ясно после просмотра стэка (Читайте первую строку). У вас есть класс `SugarContext`, который вы не выложили сюда. Объект этого класса вы неверно инстансировали. Где-то валяется `null` указатель, на объект этого класса, а вы его где-то передали в функцию. Выкладывайте сюда `SugarContext`, я может быть найду ошибку.

Comment: хм.. нет такого класса у меня. Опять же, на видео от куда я это брал этого класса тоже не было и все работало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне всё ясно c этим кодом. Это пример не сколько на программирование, сколько на повторное использование кода. Вот моя рекомендация вам:

1. Пусть вы нашли код где-то и он не компилится. Вполне возможно, что код выложили не полностью. Используйте advegoplagiatus, чтобы найти аналогичные куски в сети.
2. В вашем примере, на сайте указан гитхаб разработчика com.github.satyan. Я [нашёл](https://github.com/satyan) этого американца идийского происхождения.  Увы, в его репозитории не оказалось этого кода. Можно долго полемизировать, почему он убрал код, но тем не менее. Кода нет. А значит отвечать по-существу нечего. Из вашего куска:

   java.lang.NullPointerException: SugarContext has not been initialized 
    properly.

Это по сути означает, что должен быть класс `SugarContext`. Его нет. 
Далее по коду,

```
Contact.listAll(Contact.class);
```

В классе `Contact` - мы не нашли этого статического метода. Его там нет. Значит по определению будет ошибка компиляции. Итого, вижу два решения:

1. Вы пишете этому индусу с просьбой прислать вам полную версию кода.
2. Вы ищете другой пример.

Comment: Да, придется искать другой пример. Вы случаем не знаете какой-нибудь?

Comment: @Виктор увы не знаю.